# Way to have a different product attribute for different website languages

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to upload product manuals to each product. Now that's done. What I want is to have a different manual for EN and different for another language...
Is there a way or module to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Scope:** allows you to declare the attribute value saving scope like **Global** ( the value of this attribute for a given product must be the same for all websites and stores on this Magento installation), **Store View** (the value of this a**ttribute for a given product can differ in all Websites and all Store Views), Website** (the value of this attribute for a given product can differ in different Websites, however it cannot differ between Store Views contained under the same Website).

Firstly, you need to check if that attribute's scope set to "global" or "store view". Go to Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes and find your attribute to check.

If your attribute's scope is "store view", you can change your product's attribute for each store view by changing your edit scope. When you open product edit page, find scope changer on top-left of page, there's a block including a dropdown labeled "Choose Store View:".